# Как заменить значения столбцов в Pandas на идентификаторы?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame, в одном из столбцов которого, список значений.

Как наиболее просто и элегантно заменить эти значения на их идентификатор?

Есть такой DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['row1', 'row2'], 'col2': ['a; b; c', 'a;d;f']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    col1    col2
0   row1    a; b; c
1   row2    a;d;f
```

Если принять, что:

```
a = 1,b = 2,c = 3,d = 4,f = 5
```

Необходимо получить такой:

```py
d = {'col1': ['row1', 'row2'], 'col2': ['a;b;c', 'a;d;f'], 'col3': ['1, 2, 3','1,4,5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    col1    col2    col3
0   row1    a;b;c   1,2,3
1   row2    a;d;f   1,4,5
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение:

```
In [60]: mapping = dict(a = 1,b = 2,c = 3,d = 4,f = 5)

In [61]: pat = [fr"\b({x})\b" for x in mapping.keys()]

In [62]: repl = [f"{x}" for x in mapping.values()]

In [63]: df["col3"] = df["col2"].replace(pat, repl, regex=True)
```

Результат:

```
In [64]: df
Out[64]:
   col1     col2     col3
0  row1  a; b; c  1; 2; 3
1  row2    a;d;f    1;4;5
```

Вспомогательные переменные:

```
In [65]: pat
Out[65]: ['\\b(a)\\b', '\\b(b)\\b', '\\b(c)\\b', '\\b(d)\\b', '\\b(f)\\b']

In [66]: repl
Out[66]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

In [67]: mapping
Out[67]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'f': 5}
```